# What is the meaning of bootstrapped in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of bootstrapped in this sentence?

I’ve built a few software businesses from scratch (all **bootstrapped**!) and I thought you might find it interesting to hear a bit more about the journey.

Comment: Have a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entrepreneurship#Bootstrapping. According to this, "bootstrapping" refers to several methods of providing startup finance which avoids seeking external investors.

Comment: @JohnGo-Soco Got it, It should be the meaning. Could you write it as an answer? So I can accepted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Bootstrapping** in business terms refers to starting a company relying on money other than outside investors. The point of it is to ensure that the entrepreneur is able to maintain control of the company - albeit with personal financial risk.

Sources:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entrepreneurship#Bootstrapping
- https://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/bootstrapping.asp

Answer (score -5):

Bootstrapping has many meanings, in this context its referring to computing.

You can read about that specifically here > https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping#Computing

Even within that context is a pretty vague expression.

You should try googling before posting though :)

Comment: If you read the question, I think you'd find that software bootstrapping is not the correct context.